# Update database method in android

Tags: android

I would like to add Task name from pop up and It automatically will add to list. So, is there any way to update database automatically. Here is my method

```
SampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("SampleDB", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                String query = "select *from TaskList";
                Cursor c = SampleDB.rawQuery(query, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                do{
                    String Task = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task"));

                    /* Add current Entry to results. */ 
                 results.add(Item);
                }while(c.moveToNext());
                 this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
```

Comment: Your method doesn't have a popup. Or a write operation. Or any data.

Comment: @RaghavSood  I have written the pop up method. But, I didn't share here. I only share the database part to show data.

Answer (score 0):

This method can add items to your database:

```
public void addTaskToDb(SQLiteDatabase database, String task) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("task", task);

    database.insert("TaskList", null, values);
}
```

And then replace your code like this:

```
SampleDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("SampleDB", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)this.getListAdapter();

this.addTaskToDb(SampleDB, Item);
adapter.add(Item);
```